# Auto rotate while reading images from sd card Android

Tags: android

i'm to Overflow and this is my first question here :)

I have an gallery, image switcher and button for capturing image from camera.
After capturing image into the SD card I want to load the image to the gallery and also show it in the image switch object. for now it work fine with one big question.

Why all the images are rotated in the gallery and the image switcher?

this is my java code :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   iSwitcher = (ImageSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.ImageSwitcher01);
        iSwitcher.setFactory(this);
        iSwitcher.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                android.R.anim.fade_in));
        iSwitcher.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                android.R.anim.fade_out));
        setAllPics();
        gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.Gallery01);
        gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this)); 
        gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                //iSwitcher.setImageResource(pics[arg2]);
                //iSwitcher.setImageURI(mUrls[arg2]);
                iSwitcher.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),(bitmap[arg2])));
            }
        });
        Button BtnGetPhoto = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.BtnGetPicture);
}
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context ctx;
        int mGalleryItemBackground;
        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            ctx = c;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mUrls.length;
            //return pics.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {

            return arg0;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {

            return arg0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {

            ImageView iView = new ImageView(ctx);
            //iView.setImageURI(mUrls[arg0]);
            iView.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),(bitmap[arg0])));
            //iView.setImageResource(pics[arg0]);
            iView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            iView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 150));
            return iView;
        }
    }
private void setAllPics(){
        File images  = new File(PATH);
        File[] imagelist = images.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {

            @Override
            public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {
                 return ((filename.endsWith(".jpg"))||(filename.endsWith(".png")));  
            }
        });
        /* There isn't enough memory to open up more than a couple camera photos */
        /* So pre-scale the target bitmap into which the file is decoded */

        /* Get the size of the ImageView */
        int targetW = 350;//iSwitcher.getWidth();
        int targetH = 220;//iSwitcher.getHeight();


        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();



        mFiles = new String[imagelist.length];
        int photoW[] = null;
        int photoH[] = null; 
        int scaleFactor[] = null ;

        photoW = new int[imagelist.length];
        photoH = new int[imagelist.length];
        scaleFactor = new int[imagelist.length];
        bitmap = new Bitmap[imagelist.length];
        for(int i= 0 ; i< imagelist.length; i++)  
            {               
                bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                mFiles[i] = imagelist[i].getAbsolutePath();  
                bitmap[i] = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mFiles[i], bmOptions);
                /* Get the size of the image */
                photoW[i] = bmOptions.outWidth;
                photoH[i] = bmOptions.outHeight;
                /* Figure out which way needs to be reduced less */

                if((targetW > 0)  || (targetH > 0 ))
                    scaleFactor[i]  = Math.min(photoW[i]/targetW, photoH[i]/targetH);
                /* Set bitmap options to scale the image decode target */
                bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor[i];
                bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;
                try{
                /* Decode the JPEG file into a Bitmap */
                bitmap[i] = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mFiles[i], bmOptions);
                //iSwitcher.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),(bitmap[i])));
                } catch (OutOfMemoryError error) {
                    error.printStackTrace();
                }

            }  


        mUrls = new Uri[mFiles.length];  

        for(int i=0; i < mFiles.length; i++)  
                {  
                    mUrls[i] = Uri.parse(mFiles[i]);     
                }


    }
private OnClickListener onClickListener =new OnClickListener(){ 

    // @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {

         switch (v.getId()){
             case R.id.BtnGetPicture:

                 Intent cameraIntent = new Intent (android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                 String imageFileName = "";
                 String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());


                 SetPathIfNotExist(PATH);
                 imageFileName = timeStamp + ".jpg";

                 File image = new File(PATH,imageFileName);
                 Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);
                 cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);

                 startActivityForResult(cameraIntent,CAMERA_REQUEST);
                     break;
                        default:

                break;
         }          

     }    
     };
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) { 
        setAllPics();
        gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this)); 

        //Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
        //imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Hi have a look at this below code. before saving your captured image do the following process. it will save the images in portrait mode. hope this will help you.

 int rotation = -1;
 rotation = ((WindowManager)getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE))
                .getDefaultDisplay().getOrientation();



    Matrix rotator = new Matrix();
    switch (rotation) {
    case (Surface.ROTATION_0):
        break;
    case (Surface.ROTATION_90):
        rotator.postRotate(270);
        break;
    case (Surface.ROTATION_180):
        rotator.postRotate(180);
        break;
    case (Surface.ROTATION_270):
        rotator.postRotate(90);
        break;


    // screen_{width,height} are applied before the rotate, so we don't
    // need to change them based on rotation.
    bmp_ss = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp_ss, 0, 0, screen_width, screen_height, rotator, false);
```

Comment: Sorry but i'm saving the image in the camera intent so where exactly i put this code?

Comment: after getting the bitmap from camera itent do above works with that bitmap. at the end you will get the corrected bitmap then write that bitmap as the image using fileoutputstream.